# Draw a pie chart with same size pieces using dc.js

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

May be my question is silly but I need to plot a pie chart using dc.js that it has years as pieces but they all need to be same size no matter group data. i got data group from crossfilter.js as same value. However i need to know that there is any other way to get pie chart with same size pieces only using dimension?

Comment: Renaming tag - `dc` is a venerable **desk calculator** from the 70's - `dc.js` is the javascript **dimensional charting** library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that's not really a pie chart anymore. However, I'd suggest doing this with a ["fake group"](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#fake-groups).

First go ahead and create a group for this, even though we won't use the values, we'll let crossfilter tally up the groups.

```
var group = dimension.group();
```

Then produce a "fake group" which, each time it's read, will set all the values to 1:

```
function all_equal_group(group) {
    function make_equal(kvs) {
        return kvs.map(function(kv) {
            return {key: kv.key, value: 1};
        });
    }
    return {
        all: function() {
            return make_equal(group.all());
        },
        top: function(N) {
            return make_equal(group.top(N));
        }
    };
}
```

The `top` function is in case you're using [capping](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/web/docs/api-latest.md#dccapmixin--capmixin). Maybe not needed here, but it won't hurt.

Apply it to your chart like this:

```
pieChart.group(all_equal_group(group));
```